# Get position coordinates for an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, location, coords

Currently working on a weather web-app for iOS. I'm trying to get the coordinates of the user and put the latitude and longitude in my Ajax request (on the api Wunderground) .

Here's my code (EDIT):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, unknownLocation);

         function getLocation(pos)
         {
           var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
           var lon = pos.coords.longitude;

            $.ajax({
                     url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ApiId/geolookup/conditions/q/"+ lat +","+ lon +".json",
                     dataType : "jsonp",

                     success : function(parsed_json) {
                        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                        var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
                        alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                     }
                  });
         }
         function unknownLocation()
         {
           alert('Could not find location');
         }
       });
    </script>
```

As you can see I "simply" have to create 2 vars lat and lon and add them in my request. I tried a lot of variants but I can't get this code working.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Did you sign up for an API key? Looks like you need one.

Comment: I have one, i just hide it in my code because you don't need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable declarations are in the middle of the .ajax call, and are making the JavaScript structure invalid. Also, I'm not sure why you're using "function($)", normally with jQuery the $ is reserved and shouldn't be used as a function parameter.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
});


function onPositionUpdate(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/ApiId/geolookup/conditions/q/"+lat+","+lon+".json",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        success : function(parsed_json) {
            var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
            var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have an error : Uncaught Reference Error : position is not defined. I thought it was an implemented variable in iOS ??

Comment: You need to get the position using the getCurrentPosition() method: http://www.digimantra.com/howto/current-location-iphone-safari-firefox-browser/

Comment: Take a look at the parsed_json response in Firebug or Web Inspector to see what properties are coming back. For me, at parsed_json.response.error.description, it gives me "this key does not exist". I think you need to provide an API key as a property in the url you are using.

Comment: If you don't have an API key, it looks like you can sign up for one at http://api.wunderground.com/weather/api/ . Once you've signed up for an API key, they should provide instructions on how to incorporate that into your http requests.